# Using only recursion to sort a linked list

Tags: c, sorting, recursion, linked-list, bubble-sort

I've just tried to sort a linked list in my own way. I tried to bubble sort it entirely with recursion. Below is my code. Sorting works fine. I just wanted to know if there are some better ways to do this. Should I have done it iteratively rather than using recursion? I'd be happy to hear some suggestions.

```
// Some preprocessing stuff ...

// definition of node

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}node;

// ... functions

int main(void)
{
 
    node *list = create_list(n);       // n is list's length
    
    sort(list, list, NULL);    
}
```

**Sort function**

```
void sort(const node *first_node, node *left, node *last_node)
{
    node *right = left->next;
    
    if (first_node == last_node)
        return;
    
    if (right == last_node)
    {
        last_node = left;
        left = first_node;
    }
    else if (right->num < left->num)
    {
        swap(&left->num, &right->num);
        left = right;
    }
    else
        left = right;    

    sort(first_node, left, last_node);
}
```

Comment: Your whole (*tail recursive*) function could be written without the recursion call as: `void sort(const node *first_node, node *left, node *last_node) { for(;;) { work(); } }` where *work* is exactly what you wrote. You don't have to worry about the compiler optimizing the recursiveness away, no worries about stack overflow with large lists.

Comment: Since you have working code and are asking for opinions and suggestions, this question is off-topic.